# Como mostrar un array con varios valores guardados en un mismo campo

Tags: php, html, ajax, array

Tengo un campo que guarda un valor de un array con varios datos separados con (,) en un mismo campo de la base de datos, como hago para mostrar esos datos para mostrar en un reporte esa información

```js
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from document where project_id in (".$project_id.
  ")");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
  $array = explode(",", $row['project_id']);
  foreach($array as $projects) {
    echo $projects;
  }
}
```

Muestra el siguiente error:

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\wamp64\www\SysCPC\ajax\documents.php on line 129

La información que debería mostrar es la de Departamento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Te falta un paso mas.  La variable $sql es un objeto con todos los registros retornados por tu query, tienes que leer cada registro para poder accesar los datos asi:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from project where id in (" . $project_id . ")");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
  echo $row['id'];      
}
```

Comment: No funciona tampoco da el siguiente warning Notice: Undefined index: project_id in C:\wamp64\www\SysCPC\ajax\documents.php on line 125no muestra nada

Comment: cambiaste esta linea? `$array = explode(",", $row['project_id']);`

Comment: $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from project where id = $project_id");
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
                        $array = explode(",", $row['project_id']);
                        foreach ($array as $projects) {
                            echo $projects;
                        }
                    }

Comment: estas seguro que el campo donde guardas los valores separados por comas se llama `project_id`?

Comment: si claro y el campo en la base de datos es tipo varchar, incluí todo para que se pueda interpretar mejor

Comment: la columna project_id no existe en la tabla project, solo en la tabla document cierto?

Comment: en la tabla project existe como Id único, en esa no esta concatenado

Comment: ya edite otra vez

Comment: Sirve pero carga solo 1 id y si hay mas id en el mismo campo solo muestra 1

Comment: Ya no me muestra ningún error pero solo me muestra 1 dato, lo tengo así: $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from document where project_id in (" . $project_id . ")");
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        $array = (explode(',', $row['project_id']));
                        foreach ($array as $projects) {                            
                            echo $projects, '<br>';
                        }
                    } y lo muestro asi: <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $projects; ?>" id="id<?php echo $projects; ?>">